# Area 51: Statistic seems wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, statistics

Hi,

The "questions per day" statistic in [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management) seems wrong. The project has 277 questions in 56 days, which, to me, makes 4,9 questions per day and not 4,4 as showed currently. How so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over the number, it gives a bit more detail: "5 questions per day on average over the past two weeks".  Originally we were doing it for all time, but the rate usually changes over the course of a beta so we changed to doing it for only the past two weeks.